# Is it possible to use a natural key for a GenericForeignKey in Django?

Tags: django, natural-key, generic-foreign-key

I have the following:

```
target_content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, related_name='target_content_type')
target_object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
target = generic.GenericForeignKey('target_content_type', 'target_object_id')
```

I would like dumpdata --natural to emit a natural key for this relation. Is this possible? If not, is there an alternative strategy that would not tie me to target's primary key?

Comment: I am curious, did you find any solution for this? I did some search but nothing helpful has come up.

Comment: not yet but I'll update this with a solution if I do find one

Comment: Could you elaborate your question? Some example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**TL;DR** - Currently there is no sane way of doing so, short of creating a custom `Serializer` / `Deserializer` pair.

The problem with models that have generic relations is that Django doesn't see `target` as a field at all, only `target_content_type` and `target_object_id`, and it tries to serialize and deserialize them individually.

The classes responsible for serializing and deserializing Django models are in the modules [`django.core.serializers.base`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/serializers/base.py) and [`django.core.serializers.python`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/serializers/python.py). All the others (`xml`, `json` and `yaml`) extend either of them (and `python` extends `base`). The field serialization is done like this (irrelevant lines ommited):

```
    for obj in queryset:
        for field in concrete_model._meta.local_fields:
                if field.rel is None:
                        self.handle_field(obj, field)
                else:
                        self.handle_fk_field(obj, field)
```

Here's the first complication: the foreign key to `ContentType` is handled ok, with natural keys as we expected. But the `PositiveIntegerField` is handled by `handle_field`, that is implemented like this:

```
def handle_field(self, obj, field):
    value = field._get_val_from_obj(obj)
    # Protected types (i.e., primitives like None, numbers, dates,
    # and Decimals) are passed through as is. All other values are
    # converted to string first.
    if is_protected_type(value):
        self._current[field.name] = value
    else:
        self._current[field.name] = field.value_to_string(obj)
```

i.e. the only possibility for customization here (subclassing `PositiveIntegerField` and defining a [custom `value_to_string`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#converting-field-data-for-serialization)) will have no effect, since the serializer won't call it. Changing the data type of `target_object_id` to something else than a integer will probably break many other stuff, so it's not an option.

We *could* define our custom `handle_field` to emit natural keys in this case, but then comes the second complication: the deserialization is done like this:

```
   for (field_name, field_value) in six.iteritems(d["fields"]):
        field = Model._meta.get_field(field_name)
        ...
            data[field.name] = field.to_python(field_value)
```

Even if we customized the `to_python` method, it acts on the `field_value` alone, out of the context of the object. It's not a problem when using integers, since it will be interpreted as the model's primary key **no matter what model it is**. But to deserialize a natural key, first we need to know which model that key belongs to, and that information isn't available unless we got a reference to the object (and the `target_content_type` field had already been deserialized).

As you can see, it's not an impossible task - supporting natural keys in generic relations - but to accomplish that a lot of things would need to be changed in the serialization and deserialization code. The steps necessary, then (if anyone feels up to the task) are:

- Create a custom `Field` extending `PositiveIntegerField`, with methods to encode/decode an object - calling the referenced models' `natural_key` and `get_by_natural_key`;
- Override the serializer's `handle_field` to call the encoder if present;
- Implement a custom deserializer that: 1) imposes some order in the fields, ensuring the content type is deserialized before the natural key; 2) calls the decoder, passing not only the `field_value` but also a reference to the decoded `ContentType`.

Answer (score 3):

I've written a custom Serializer and Deserializer which supports GenericFK's. Checked it briefly and it seems to do the job.

This is what I came up with:

```
import json

from django.contrib.contenttypes.generic import GenericForeignKey
from django.utils import six
from django.core.serializers.json import Serializer as JSONSerializer
from django.core.serializers.python import Deserializer as \
    PythonDeserializer, _get_model
from django.core.serializers.base import DeserializationError
import sys


class Serializer(JSONSerializer):

    def get_dump_object(self, obj):
        dumped_object = super(CustomJSONSerializer, self).get_dump_object(obj)
        if self.use_natural_keys and hasattr(obj, 'natural_key'):
            dumped_object['pk'] = obj.natural_key()
            # Check if there are any generic fk's in this obj
            # and add a natural key to it which will be deserialized by a matching Deserializer.
            for virtual_field in obj._meta.virtual_fields:
                if type(virtual_field) == GenericForeignKey:
                    content_object = getattr(obj, virtual_field.name)
                    dumped_object['fields'][virtual_field.name + '_natural_key'] = content_object.natural_key()
        return dumped_object


def Deserializer(stream_or_string, **options):
    """
    Deserialize a stream or string of JSON data.
    """
    if not isinstance(stream_or_string, (bytes, six.string_types)):
        stream_or_string = stream_or_string.read()
    if isinstance(stream_or_string, bytes):
        stream_or_string = stream_or_string.decode('utf-8')
    try:
        objects = json.loads(stream_or_string)
        for obj in objects:
            Model = _get_model(obj['model'])
            if isinstance(obj['pk'], (tuple, list)):
                o = Model.objects.get_by_natural_key(*obj['pk'])
                obj['pk'] = o.pk
                # If has generic fk's, find the generic object by natural key, and set it's
                # pk according to it.
                for virtual_field in Model._meta.virtual_fields:
                    if type(virtual_field) == GenericForeignKey:
                        natural_key_field_name = virtual_field.name + '_natural_key'
                        if natural_key_field_name in obj['fields']:
                            content_type = getattr(o, virtual_field.ct_field)
                            content_object_by_natural_key = content_type.model_class().\
                            objects.get_by_natural_key(obj['fields'][natural_key_field_name][0])
                            obj['fields'][virtual_field.fk_field] = content_object_by_natural_key.pk
        for obj in PythonDeserializer(objects, **options):
            yield obj
    except GeneratorExit:
        raise
    except Exception as e:
        # Map to deserializer error
        six.reraise(DeserializationError, DeserializationError(e), sys.exc_info()[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated the OmriToptix [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36408745/6696848) for Django 2.2 and above.

In Django 2.0:

> The Model._meta.virtual_fields attribute is removed.

So, the new Serializer and Deserializer:

```
import json

from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.utils import six
from django.core.serializers.json import Serializer as JSONSerializer
from django.core.serializers.python import Deserializer as \
    PythonDeserializer, _get_model
from django.core.serializers.base import DeserializationError
import sys


class Serializer(JSONSerializer):

    def get_dump_object(self, obj):
        dumped_object = super(JSONSerializer, self).get_dump_object(obj)

        if hasattr(obj, 'natural_key'):
            dumped_object['pk'] = obj.natural_key()
            for field in obj._meta.get_fields():
                if type(field) == GenericForeignKey:
                    content_object = getattr(obj, field.name)
                    dumped_object['fields'][field.name + '_natural_key'] = content_object.natural_key()
        return dumped_object


def Deserializer(stream_or_string, **options):
    if not isinstance(stream_or_string, (bytes, six.string_types)):
        stream_or_string = stream_or_string.read()
    if isinstance(stream_or_string, bytes):
        stream_or_string = stream_or_string.decode('utf-8')
    try:
        objects = json.loads(stream_or_string)
        for obj in objects:
            Model = _get_model(obj['model'])
            if isinstance(obj['pk'], (tuple, list)):
                o = Model.objects.get_by_natural_key(*obj['pk'])
                obj['pk'] = o.pk
                for field in Model._meta.get_fields():
                    if type(field) == GenericForeignKey:
                        natural_key_field_name = field.name + '_natural_key'
                        if natural_key_field_name in obj['fields']:
                            content_type = getattr(o, field.ct_field)
                            content_object_by_natural_key = content_type.model_class().\
                            objects.get_by_natural_key(*obj['fields'][natural_key_field_name])
                            obj['fields'][field.fk_field] = content_object_by_natural_key.pk
                            del obj['fields'][natural_key_field_name]

        for obj in PythonDeserializer(objects, **options):
            yield obj
    except GeneratorExit:
        raise
    except Exception as e:
        six.reraise(DeserializationError, DeserializationError(e), sys.exc_info()[2])
```

Then, in your settings.py, set this configuration:

```
    SERIALIZATION_MODULES = {
    "json": "path.to.serializer_file"
  }
```

Now, you can use:

```
python3 manage.py dumpdata --natural-foreign --natural-primary > dump.json
```

Other way, if you need to dump some data (filter querysets), you can make it from code:

```
from path.to.serializers import Serializer, Deserializer

# Serialize
registers = YourModel.objects.filter(some_attribute=some_value)
dump = Serializer().serialize(registers, use_natural_foreign_keys=True, use_natural_primary_keys=True)

# Deserialize
for deserialized_object in Deserializer(dump, use_natural_foreign_keys=True, use_natural_primary_keys=True):
    print(deserialized_object.object)  # See here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/serialization/
```